# How to change Search API index field machine name?

Tags: 7, search

I am using Search API and Search API Solr modules on drupal 7. I have also drupal 8 and drupal 9 sites, and all those sites are indexed on the same solr index. So I need the same machine name for indexed fields on Solr index. For this purpose, I need to change marked machine names.
Solr index field names are generated from those machine names.
[image]
For drupal 7 I can't find a field mapping solution like [Search API field map](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_field_map) module for drupal 8, 9.
Is there any solution to override those fields' machine names in index creation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer I found in search_api_solr module search_api_solr.api.php file. I used **hook_search_api_solr_field_mapping_alter**

```
/**
 * Change the way the index's field names are mapped to Solr field names.
 *
 * @param SearchApiIndex $index
 *   The index whose field mappings are altered.
 * @param array $fields
 *   An associative array containing the index field names mapped to their Solr
 *   counterparts. The special fields 'search_api_id' and 'search_api_relevance'
 *   are also included.
 */
 function hook_search_api_solr_field_mapping_alter(SearchApiIndex $index, 
                                                               array &$fields) {
   if ($index->entity_type == 'node' && isset($fields['body:value'])) {
    $fields['body:value'] = 'tm_text';
   }
 }
```

Here you can add required Solr index field name('tm_text') for according field('body:value').